# Spring event publisher is not waiting listener

Tags: java, spring, event-listener

I have 3 classes on 2 different projects. I want to publish event from one project and wait for the end of the listener method on the other project. But in my case publisher method is not waiting for the listeners. After the end of publisher method, listener methods starts running.

Here is Minimal, Reproducible Example:

In project 1 I have 2 classes:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;

public class ConfigEvent extends ApplicationEvent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 144711L;

    public ConfigEvent(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }
}



@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @Bean
    public Object object(Object unnecessaryObject) {
        System.out.println("Before publish");
        publisher.publishEvent(new ConfigEvent(this));
        System.out.println("After publish");
        Object obj= new Object ();

        System.out.println("End of publisher");
        return obj;
    }
}
```

In project 2:

```
@Component
public class MyConfig implements ApplicationListener<ConfigEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ConfigEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Start of Event listener");
        System.out.println("End of Event listener");
    }
}
```

In the above case output order is like this:

- Before publish
- After publish
- End of publish method
- Start of Event listener
- End of Event listener

My publisher method was waiting for the listeners. But after the changing spring version, it's not waiting anymore.

Here is the expected output order:

- Before publish
- Start of Event listener
- End of Event listener
- After publish
- End of publish method

Is there a bug or this is the correct working of application listeners? And what can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Probably by design. Don't count on `publishEvent` calling all listeners synchronously.

Comment: @Jorn No. It is synchronous by default. You annotate your listener with `@Async` if it can be async. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListener.html They haven't used that annotation, so they can count on it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the ApplicationEventPublisher.html documentation. [https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEventPublisher.html#publishEvent(java.lang.Object)][1]

> Such an event publication step is effectively a hand-off to the multicaster and does not imply synchronous/asynchronous execution or even immediate execution at all. Event listeners are encouraged to be as efficient as possible, individually using asynchronous execution for longer-running and potentially blocking operations.